# Pipes not displaying in flappy bird game for pygame with NEAT

Tags: python, pygame

I was following a tutorial with tech with time and at the end of part 4 every thing was working, part 5 just explains neat then there was implementation of neat in part 6 and by the time we tested the code again half way through part 7 (the last part) it was not working properly but no error codes.

I have tried moving the pygame.display.update() to different locations and it does not seem to help.

I have tried changing the draw order so that the birds are drawn first and then the pipes and it did not seem to help.

```
import pygame, neat, time, os, random

pygame.font.init()

WIN_WIDTH = 576
WIN_HEIGHT = 900

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('flappybird_pics/yellowbird-downflap.png')), #.convert_alpha()
             pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('flappybird_pics/yellowbird-midflap.png')), #.convert_alpha()
             pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('flappybird_pics/yellowbird-upflap.png'))] #.convert_alpha()

PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('flappybird_pics/pipe-green.png')) #.convert()

BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('flappybird_pics/base.png')) #.convert()

BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('flappybird_pics/background-day.png')) #.convert()

STAT_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)


class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel * self.tick_count + 1.5 * self.tick_count ** 2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
             self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4+1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

class Pipe:
    GAP = 200
    VEL = 5

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.height = 0

        self.top = 0
        self.bottom = 0
        self.PIPE_TOP = pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG, False, True)
        self.PIPE_BOTTOM = PIPE_IMG

        self.passed = False
        self.set_height()

    def set_height(self):
        self.height = random.randrange(50, 450) #todo check this
        self.top = self.height - self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
        self.bottom = self.height + self.GAP

    def move(self):
        self.x -= self.VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.PIPE_TOP, (self.x, self.top))
        win.blit(self.PIPE_BOTTOM, (self.x, self.bottom))

    def collide(self, bird):
        bird_mask = bird.get_mask()
        top_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_TOP)
        bottom_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_BOTTOM)

        top_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.top - round(bird.y))
        bottom_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.bottom - round(bird.y))

        b_point = bird_mask.overlap(bottom_mask, bottom_offset)
        t_point = bird_mask.overlap(top_mask, top_offset)

        if t_point or b_point:
            return True

        return  False

class Base:
    VEL = 5
    WIDTH = BASE_IMG.get_width()
    IMG = BASE_IMG

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x1 = 0
        self.x2 = self.WIDTH

    def move(self):
        self.x1 -= self.VEL
        self.x2 -= self.VEL

        if self.x1 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x1 = self.x2 + self.WIDTH

        if self.x2 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x2 = self.x1 + self.WIDTH

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x1, self.y))
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x2, self.y))

def draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))

    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.draw(win)

    text = STAT_FONT.render("Score: " + str(score), 1, (255,255,255))
    win.blit(text, (WIN_WIDTH - 10 - text.get_width(), 10))

    base.draw(win)
    for bird in birds:
        bird.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()


def main(genomes, config):
    nets = []
    ge = []
    birds = []

    for _, g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        birds.append(Bird(230,350))
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g)

    base = Base(730) # todo twick
    pipes = [Pipe(700)]
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    score = 0

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            pipe_ind = 0
            if len(birds) > 0:
                if len(pipes) > 1 and birds[0].x > pipes[0].x + pipes[0].PIPE_TOP.get_width():
                    pipe_ind = 1
            else:
                run = False
                break

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            bird.move()
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            output = nets[x].activate((bird.y, abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].height), abs(bird.y -
                                                                                         pipes[pipe_ind].bottom)))

            if output[0] > 0.5:
                bird.jump()

        add_pipe = False
        rem = []
        for pipe in pipes:
             for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
                if pipe.collide(bird):
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1
                    birds.pop(x)
                    ge.pop(x)

                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < birds[0].x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True

        if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
            rem.append(pipe)

            pipe.move()

        if add_pipe:
            score += 1
            for g in ge:
                g.fitness += 5
            pipes.append(Pipe(700))

        for r in rem:
            pipes.remove(r)

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() > 730 or bird.y < 0:
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)

        base.move()
        draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score)


def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet,
                                neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)

    p = neat.Population(config)

    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    winner = p.run(main, 50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config.txt")
    run(config_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). This means that `pipe.move()` is never called and the pipes remain on the far right out of the window:

```py
def main(genomes, config):
    # [...]

    run = True
    while run:
        # [...]

        add_pipe = False
        rem = []
        for pipe in pipes:
             for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
                if pipe.collide(bird):
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1
                    birds.pop(x)
                    ge.pop(x)

                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < birds[0].x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True

        # INDENTATION
        #-->|
            if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                rem.append(pipe)

            pipe.move()

        # [...]
```

Comment: yep that was it, thank you so much

Comment: sorry still new, thank you